# Pass array from client side to service side c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I am calling a javascript function on button click using onclientclick with below function.

```
 function addValues() {
        debugger;
        var arrValue = [];
        var hdnValue = document.getElementById("hdn").value;
        var strValue = hdnValue.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < strValue.length; i++) {
            var ddlValue = document.getElementById(strValue[i]).value;
            arrValue.push(ddlValue);
        }
    }
```

`arrValue` array will have all the required values and how can I move this array values to server side for further process.

**Update 1:**

**HTML:**

```
function addValues() {
        debugger;
        var arrddlValue = [];
        var hdnddlValue = document.getElementById("hdnDDL").value;
        var strddlValue = hdnddlValue.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < strddlValue.length; i++) {
            var ddlValue = document.getElementById(strddlValue[i]).value;
            arrddlValue.push(ddlValue);              
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        data: { ddlArray: arrddlValue },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (x, e) {
        }
    });
```

**Code:**

```
protected void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Request["ddlArray[]"] != null)
            {
                string[] arrValues = Array.ConvertAll(Request["ddlArray[]"].ToString().Split(','), s => (s));
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Use [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: Let us know your feedback about answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your framework is ASP.Net you can pass it by `$.ajax`, I am passing array like:

```
$.ajax({
url: '',
data: {  AbArray: arrValue },
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
async: true,
success: function (data) {

},
error: function (x, e) { 
}
```

});

and get it in Back-end like:

```
if (request["AbArray[]"] != null)
{
    int[] arrValues = Array.ConvertAll(request["AbArray[]"].ToString().Split(','), s => int.Parse(s));
}
```

suppose array is `int`.

the above sample is using `Generic-Handler`.

if you want to use `webmethod` do something like:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static void PassArray(List<int> arr)
{ 
}
```

and Ajax would be like:

```
function addValues() {
debugger;
var arrddlValue = [];
var hdnddlValue = document.getElementById("hdnDDL").value;
var strddlValue = hdnddlValue.split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < strddlValue.length; i++) {
    var ddlValue = document.getElementById(strddlValue[i]).value;
    arrddlValue.push(ddlValue);
} 
var jsonVal = JSON.stringify({ arr: arrValue });
$.ajax({
    url: 'YourPage.aspx/PassArray',
    data: jsonVal,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (x, e) {
    }
});
}
```

Change Ajax Url as your `PassArray` address which mean `YourPage.aspx` should be change to page name which have `PassArray` in it's code-behind.

For more info **[Read This](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)**.

Comment: I tried and unable to get values in server side on button click. Updated my post and please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @vicky , There are some probs with your code, 1- You should define `webmethod` 2- ajax url is null correct it 3- that code should be in webmethod not button click 4- Call that ajax in client-side at end of `addValues` in JavaScript .

Comment: @Aria - function addValues() {
            debugger;
            var arrddlValue = [];
            var hdnddlValue = document.getElementById("hdn").value;
            var strddlValue = hdnddlValue.split(',');
            for (var i = 0; i < strddlValue.length; i++) {
                var ddlValue = document.getElementById(strddlValue[i]).value;
                arrddlValue.push(ddlValue);
            } `put ajax function here`
        } - Is this the place?

Comment: Got it now. And how can I get the passarray method values in my button click event for further process.

Comment: You need save it in session or cookie or something else to get it in btn_click for further process, please read more about ASP.Net and JQuery

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Asp.net WebForm Application,

Approach 1 :  you can store your array value in a hidden input control and retrieve the saved data in your c# coding.

Approach 2 :  define web method in your server side c# code and pass this javascript array value as ajax call.

link for Approach 1 : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-JavaScript-variable-value-to-Server-Side-Code-Behind-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

link for Approach 2 : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-receive-JavaScript-Array-to-Web-Service-Web-Method-using-ASP.Net-AJAX.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would "stringify" the array by imploding it with a special char unlikely to appear in my values (for example: §), and then with the help of jQuery.ajax() function, I will send it to the backend (ASP.NET MVC) action method:

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'http://a-domain.com/MyController/MyAction',
   type : 'POST'
   data : 'data=' + myStringifiedArray;
});
```

My backend would be something like this (in MyController class):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(string data)
{
    string[] arrValue = data.Split('§');
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

For ASP.NET forms, the ajax request would be:

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'http://a-domain.com/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod',
   type : 'POST'
   data : 'data=' + myStringifiedArray;
});
```

And the backend would be something like this:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void MyMethod(string data)
{
    string[] arrValue = data.Split('§');
    ...
}
```

You will find a more precise explanation here: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

Comment: This is not MVC app.

Comment: I updated the answer, please check. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is not type-safe because `MyMethod` is not clear as entered parameter is `string` not `int[]` or `List<int>`, and you should cast array to string in client-side.